# How to hook up an event to an event in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

Is it possible to hook up an event to another event in VB8?
I have this code in C#...

```
public event ShowAboutDialog = delegate {};
private void hookupEvents() {
  myButton.Click += ShowAboutDialog;
}
```

And am trying to convert it into VB8, but can't get it to work..

```
Public Event ShowAboutDialog As EventHandler
Private Sub HookupEvents()
    AddHandler AboutMenuItem.Click, AddressOf ShowAboutDialog
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to pass the name of the event handler routine after **AddressOf**

```
Private Sub HookupEvents()
    AddHandler AboutMenuItem.Click, AddressOf ShowAboutDialog
End Sub

Public Sub ShowAboutDialog(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this the only way to do it in VB? Is there no way to hook the AboutMenuItem.Click event to another event, without using a routine?